# How to write code in functional way in Js

Tags: javascript, sorting

How do we write code in a functional manner inside Javascript?

So what I initially did was something like this

```
render ()  {

    if (!this.props.mainListFetching && !this.props.mainListError) {
      let testData = this.sortAmountPledgingMaximumOrMinimum(this.props.mainList, "maximum")
      console.log(testData) //Coming out to be undefined
        this.sortTypeTownOrCountry(this.props.mainList)
        this.sortPercentHighestOrLeast(this.props.mainList)

    }
```

this calls the following function

```
 sortPercentHighestOrLeast = (data, type) => {
       data.sort((a, b) => {
           if (type == "maximum") {
            return (
                a["percentage.funded"] - b["percentage.funded"]
            )
        } else {
            return (
                b["percentage.funded"] - a["percentage.funded"]
            )
        }
     }) 
     console.log(data)
     return data
}
```

I was expecting the result from the above function will be saved in my `testData` variable but when I `console.log`, it is coming out to be undefined.

My `console.log(data)` is printing result in console which confirms that function is executing and data isn't undefined?

**[Update:]** I have also tried this (since Js is async)

```
 let testData =  this.sortAmountPledgingMaximumOrMinimum(this.props.mainList, "maximum", (data) => {
            console.log("anything") //Doesn't log anything
          })
```

Comment: Looks odd, are you sure that's the exact code you're using? Can you post a live [MCVE] that illustrates the problem? If `data.sort` doesn't throw an error due to `data` being undefined, then the function *should* return something that isn't `undefined`

Comment: Shouldn't `a["percentage.funded"]` be `a.percentage.funded`? Are you sure the key is `"percentage.funded"`? BTW, `sort` mutates the original array.

Comment: Do note that `.sortAmountPledgingMaximumOrMinimum` (what generates `testData`) is *not* the same function as `sortPercentHighestOrLeast` (the function you posted in the second code block). What is `sortAmountPledgingMaximumOrMinimum`?

Comment: please add the data as well.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That fixed it.

Comment: Then the problem is in `sortAmountPledgingMaximumOrMinimum()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance if I do  `let testData =  this.sortPercentHighestOrLeast(this.props.mainList, "maximum", (data) => {
            console.log("anything") //Doesn't log anything
          })`
Can't we do synchronous coding like this?

Comment: For that to work, you would need `sortPercentHighestOrLeast` to accept a third parameter, a callback (but that doesn't seem necessary, because everything here is synchronous). But. as has been said already, you need to post the code in your `sortAmountPledgingMaximumOrMinimum` function so that the problem can be identified.

Comment: I don't there is a problem any more @CertainPerformance as it was the wrong function name... The OP said "That fixed it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `funded` is a nested property of `percentage`, you could move the check of the condition a step ahead because you check for each sorting iteration.

```
sortPercentHighestOrLeast = (data, type) => data.sort(type => type === "maximum"
    ? (a, b) => a.percentage.funded - b.percentage.funded
    : (a, b) => b.percentage.funded - a.percentage.funded
);
```

Comment: are you sure it will work? For some reason i don't see any changes in my data

Comment: you don't even add your data to the question, so i assume, it should work. btw, why do you assume to get an answer without supplying data of the array?

Comment: Sorry my bad and thanks for answering the question. btw - I think original question didn't actually require you to have data since console.log of the function was logging something but when I was doing  `console.log(testData) ` it was coming out to be undefined. 
@CertainPerformance pointed out my mistake in comment section.